# Form automatically submits when I don't want it to?

Tags: javascript, forms

Every time I run any function using a button, the form gets automatically submitted, even though it shouldn't be submitted until the final button is pressed. This doesn't happen outside the <form> tag.

Code:

```
<div class = "form">
    <form name = "contactForm" onsubmit="validateForm()">
        <li>
            <label>First name: </label><input type = "text" name = "fname" autofocus>
        </li><br>
        <li>
            <label>Last Name: </label><input type = "text" name = "lname">
        </li><br>
        <li>
            <label>Email: </label>
            <input type = "text"name = "email"> 
            <button onclick = "validateEmail()">Check if email is valid</button>
        </li><br>
        <li>
            <label>Message: </label><br>
            <textarea rows = "10" cols = "50" name = "message"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li> 
            <input type = "submit">
        </li>
    </form>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note that if you don't specify `type` attribute, button element behaves like `type="submit"`.

Comment: I see an opening `<div>` and a closing `</ul>`, and the `<li>` elements aren't in a wrapping set of `<ul>` and `</ul>`. This is separate of your question, but clean code is easier to work with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this..

```
<button onclick = "validateEmail();return false">
```

Answer (score 2):

The [default behavior](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.html) of a `button` element is to submit the form in which it is contained. That is, the default value of its `type` attribute is `submit`. To prevent a `button` element from submitting automatically, set its type to `button`, which has no default behavior.